# C++ class/struct member field ordering

Tags: c++, class, memory-management, struct

I have a class/struct in C++(language dependent question) that gets instantiated/destroyed a lot. It kind of looks like this:

```
Class example {
    ulong firstField;
    bool secondField;
    //rest of code etc...
}
```

Does it matter if I declare the ulong first or the bool first? I know in languages like Java or Python it doesn't matter but I heard from that this is something to keep in mind for making games using C++

If it does matter, which one should be put first and why?

Comment: Unless you target a small embedded system where every single byte counts, then no it doesn't matter.

Comment: You need to have at least 3 fields before it matters.  Google "c++ class member alignment" for basic hits.